# Web Server/Site Python

Tags: python

So I was wondering if there is any Python package that can allow a pure Python application with a graphic interface to be embedded in a website. I have an application with a Tkinter interface that I want to make available on a website. Any way to do this without converting too much code?

Thanks!

Comment: First, it would depend on the graphic library you use, which in your case is Tkinter. Secondly, I don't think any “classic” graphic library provides this feature, as graphical apps and web apps have a very different design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's possible: GTK3 has a html5 backend named [Broadway](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html).
This backend enable to access to an application through a web browser.

```
$ GDK_BACKEND=broadway your-application
```

You can see an exemple with python in this [video](http://vimeo.com/25108293)

Of course, it needs a GTK application...

Comment: It probably should be mentioned that this is kind of experimental and AFAIK nobody is seriously using it.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.

Python/Tkinter app is a desktop application, which requires desktop manager, has access to file system etc.

Web application is a different stack of technologies (HTTP, HTML, javascript etc), it is not possible to mix them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but not in way you expect.

There is [python - to js translation kit](http://pyjs.org/), which supports many, but not all, python operations, functions and types.

So you can write back-end and front-end in python.

But using pure js for front-end will give you more performance.

Comment: it doesn't support Tkinter. Yet, in other cases it is extremely useful - I've got 5x speedup after porting a Python project to JS and then running it via V8 binding.